# Organic Tabs cannot display images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use organic tabs but the content includes images cannot displayed. Like image below :

[image]

Here is content when is active :

```
<div class="hide" id="hard">
  <div id="recent"></div>
<!-- call content by id recent -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery("#recent").MyFn({
      //                    
       });
  </script>
</div>
```

and here is Organic Tabs :

```
            <script>
              $(function() {
                  $("#example-two").organicTabs({

                  });
              });
            </script>
```

How to view image when tab is active. Problem with only chrome browser.

Comment: Can you show us your css?

Comment: @Donte'Trumble: Not by CSS. Sometime, it views ok. Problem with only Google Chrome. Firefox and IE view ok.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble:. Sometimes, it also cannot view with append in jQuery. Simple Example : $("#recent").append("My content");

Comment: I need a refresh to run again when tab is active. For default, Chrome cookie break it with display:none when it is not active yet.